# What corner cases must we consider when parsing $PATH on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix, environment-variables, glibc

I'm working on a C application that has to walk $PATH to find full pathnames for binaries, and the only allowed dependency is glibc (i.e. no calling external programs like which). In the normal case, this just entails splitting getenv("PATH") by colons and checking each directory one by one, but I want to be sure I cover all of the possible corner cases. What gotchas should I look out for? In particular, are relative paths, paths starting with ~ meant to be expanded to $HOME, or paths containing the : char allowed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One thing that once surprised me is that the empty string in `PATH` means the current directory. Two adjacent colons or a colon at the end or beginning of `PATH` means the current directory is included. This is documented in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for instance.

It also is in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

So

```
PATH=:/bin
PATH=/bin:
PATH=/bin::/usr/bin
```

All mean the current directory is in `PATH`

Comment: +1 After checking through the source code for `which`, it seems this is the only corner case. `which` first checks if a full path was given and the file is executable. It will then prepend each component of the path and check again, replacing an empty path component with the current directory.

Comment: Following the spec, the implementation of `which`, and some common standard shells should give a pretty good perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a problem with Linux in general, but make sure that your code works if `PATH` has some funky (like, UTF-8) encoding to deal with directories with fancy letters. I suspect this might depend on the filesystem encoding.

I remember working on a bug report of some russian guy who had fancy letters in his user name (and hence, his home directory name which appeared in `PATH`).

Comment: Nope, encoding is irrelevant to `PATH`. If a program considers it, it's buggy.

Comment: @R.: Interesting; do you have some specifications to support that claim? My understanding is that in order to parse `PATH`, you need to treat it as a sequence of characters (instead of a sequence of `bytes`), hence you need to be aware of the encoding.

Comment: The only character that is special in `PATH` is `:`, so the only time your claim might have some validity is with legacy Windows-oriented CJK encodings, but these are usually considered unusable on Unix.

Comment: @R.: It's true that the colon is special for splitting the `PATH` value. However, this is not sufficient. Imagine you want to actually *do* something with the paths, like printing them to the screen (using the local 8 bit encoding) or sending them as UTF-8 encoded strings over the wire so another computer can adore the fancy russian characters in your home directory name. In those cases you have to perform a string conversion, which requires that you know what the string is currently encoded in.

Comment: No, you don't. On any properly configured system, the locale's encoding and filesystem encoding match. All you do is print it. If they don't match, there's no standard way to know what the encodings are and nothing you can do. Of course any modern system will be all-UTF-8 anyway... Finally, the normal thing to **do** with a `PATH` is not to print it but to search it for a file (program) to run, in which case encoding is always irrelevant.

Comment: @R..: Not quite; `'\0'` is also special.  (I suppose that probably goes without saying.)

Answer (score 1):

This is minor but I'll added it since it hasn't already been mentioned. $PATH can include both absolute and relative paths.  If your crawling the paths list by chdir(2)ing into each directory, you need to keep track of the original working directory (getcwd(3)) and chdir(2) back to it at each iteration of the crawl.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers cover most of it, but it's worth covering parts of the question that wasn't answered yet:

1. $ and ~ are not special in the value of $PATH.
2. If $PATH is not set at all, `execvp()` will use a default value.