# how to smart append LD_LIBRARY_PATH in shell when nounset

Tags: bash, shell

In following shell, error shows **LD_LIBRARY_PATH: unbound variable** if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH not set.

Can I use similar usage like ${xxx:-yyy} to simplified it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could use this construct:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Explanation:

- If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set, then `${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` expands to nothing without evaluating `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, thus the result is equivalent to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath` and no error is raised.
- If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set, then `${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` expands to `:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, thus the result is equivalent to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

See the [Bash Reference Manual / 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more information on these expansions.

This is an important security practice as two adjacent colons or a trailing/leading colon count as adding the **current directory** to `$PATH` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See also:

- [What corner cases must we consider when parsing path on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121753/what-corner-cases-must-we-consider-when-parsing-path-on-linux)
- [bash: $PATH ending in colon puts working directory in PATH](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775704)
- [How Torch broke ls](https://joshumax.github.io/general/2017/06/08/how-torch-broke-ls.html)