# Why current directory can be searched by the dynamic linker by default?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, dynamic-linking

I'm trying some practices with the dynamic linker in ubuntu-20 (ld-linux.so.2)
But one peculiar thing is that the current directory is automatically included in the searching list

I couldn't find any descriptions how this can be done
Because the man page specifies the searching order but there is nothing about the current directory (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)

Even though the executable cannot be run as I expected if I `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
But I'm still confused because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't have the current working directory
And `LD_RUN_PATH` has nothing in it as well

```
$ pwd
/home/mk/work/test
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/mk/local/lib:
$ echo $LD_RUN_PATH
```

Could you please share the reason why this can be done?
The tested code is as below

```
$ cat foo.cpp 

#include <iostream>

void whoami()
{
  std::cout << "I'm foo" << std::endl;
}

$ cat main.cpp

#include <iostream>

void whoami();

int main()
{
  whoami();
  return 0;
}

$ g++ -o libfoo.so -shared -fpic foo.cpp
$ g++ main.cpp -Wl,-Bdynamic libfoo.so
$ ./a.out 
I'm foo
```

Comment: Show output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you for your answer, it was the problem. But actually I'm still confused because LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't have the current working directory. But if I unset it as `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the dynamic linker cannot find the dynamic library and fails to run the executable as it supposed to do. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: No, but you could study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and you are allowed to improve it since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You might also consider using [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/) instead

Comment: Thank you for your comment, If I have a chance I will give it a try. Unfortunately I'm not considering musl-libc for now. I just hope that someone can reproduce this issue as well. If then I will consider raising a bug on their bugzilla. But I want to check it out clearly before doing so.

Comment: You could also study the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of your [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0). See http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Answer (score 1):

After doing some tests,
I found that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works in the same way as `PATH`
which means the current working directory is automatically included into it
if I add colon(`:`) as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon

references as below

[What corner cases must we consider when parsing $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121753/what-corner-cases-must-we-consider-when-parsing-path-on-linux)
[how to smart append LD_LIBRARY_PATH in shell when nounset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631228/how-to-smart-append-ld-library-path-in-shell-when-nounset)

Comment: Note that searching current working directory for shared libraries is exceedingly bad idea (TM).You should _never_ do this in practice.

Comment: @EmployedRussian thank you for your comment, It must be grateful if you share the reason why it is a bad practice with me

Comment: @huykmyog: obvious cybersecurity reasons come immediately to mind... Your current directory (e.g. when it is `/tmp/` or `$HOME/Downloads` ....) could contain a bad `libc.so`